# Разметка панели Grid

Tags: wpf, c#

Подскажите, можно ли при создании Grid в разметке XAML указать сразу нужное количество строк и столбцов (при условии, что они будут равного размера), а не делать для каждых строки и столбца RowDefinition и ColumnDefinition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если известно, что все столбцы и строки равного размера, то можно вместо элемента Grid использовать элемент [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx).

```
<UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что он не умеет того что вы хотите. Вам придётся либо копипастить нужные элементы, либо создавать их динамических с помощью цикла.